# Javascript variables - setting as percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="contentBlockOne">
        <span class="moreButton">More</span>
        <br />Each block will have an article summary in it.</div>
```

I want to increase the width of "Div" on a "Span" click with the following jQuery ( I havn't bothered including the else part):

```
            var currentWidth = $('.moreButton').parent().width();               
            $('.moreButton').click(function () {
                if ($(this).parent().width == currentWidth) {
                    $(this).parent().animate({ width: '98%' }, 800);                        
                    $(this).text('Less');
                }
```

In my head the "currentWidth" variaeble should be the same as the parents width. But when debugging, the code does not do anything. I presume it is because the, for what ever reason, the two width values are not the same.

Comment: Why are you prefacing your questions with the word _"More?"_

Answer (score 4):

You're missing parentheses on the `.width()` call. Change:

```
if ($(this).parent().width == currentWidth) {
// to
if ($(this).parent().width() == currentWidth) {
```